# Show downloaded PDF file with webView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, webview

I'm making an iPhone app, that will download a PDF file and display it in a webView.
However my script will not show the downloaded PDF. It does download it and save it in Documents, but the webView will not show it.

Here's my script:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *urlen = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlen];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: What actually happens?  Do you get any errors?  Does anything show?

Comment: Hi, yeah forgot to write them... ;-)
I get: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"
It works if I put the pdf file ind folder from the beginning, but when I download the pdf from the web, it makes that error...

Comment: There's a lot more information associated with that error... what line does it actually happen on?  And what's the actual stack-trace?

Comment: First, Im green with this kind of code, so hope I don't ask dumb!?
But the line it shows me that "Thread 1:..." is on:
NSURL *urlen = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: And it writes:
DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Can you edit this into the question?  These details should be included as part of the question (and any future questions you might ask, remember to include these sorts of details in the question itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation on `NSURL` [official documentation on `NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a).

Sending `nil` as the argument to `fileURLWithPath:` produces an exception.

The problem then is actually with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]`.  This is returning `nil`, rather than an actual path to a file.

The problem here is actually that `[NSBundle mainBundle]` refers to files that are bundle with your app.  You need to look in your app's document directory, which is where it stores files it has downloaded.

This method will give you the path to your app's document directory:

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```

Now, just append the file name to this path:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3.pdf"];
```

And for good measure (because crashes are always bad), make sure the file exists as such:

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pdfPath];
```

And finish as such:

```
if (fileExists) {
    NSURL *urlen = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlen];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
} else {
    // probably let the user know there's some sort of problem
}
```

Comment: Damn, you are good...! It works, thank you so much. I have tried to figure out this problem the last couple of days, and now it just works!! Thanks a lot..